# Comparing elements of two vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am new to c++ and trying to understand vectors, my requirement is to compare the values of each index in two vectors.

Below is the pseudocode which works for arrays but not for standard vector class, size of array can be calculated by

```
mySize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);

for(int i = 0;i<mySize;i++)
{
  if(a[i] == b[i])
  {
  std::cout <<": Match ";
  }
  else
  {
   std::cout <<":Doesnt Match" ;
  }

}
```

but while iam trying to use vectors, it isn't as simple

1.Does Range Based Loops work for the above scenario? 
2. How do i get the size of vector , below code is actually showing the extra memory than i have created, 
probably std::vector vet allocates extra space by default

```
 std::vector<int> vec;
 vec.push_back( -10 );
 vec.push_back( -20 );
 vec.push_back( -20 );
 vec.push_back( -20 );
 vec.push_back( -20 );
 for (int i=0;i<sizeof(vec);i++)
 {
     std::cout<<vec[i]<<"\t";    
 }

 output :

 10 -20 -20 -20 -20 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0      0    0   0   0   0   0
```

Code Update after comments

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back( -10 );
vec.push_back( -20 );
vec.push_back( -20 );
vec.push_back( -20 );
vec.push_back( -20 )

std::vector<int> vec1;
vec1.push_back( -20 );
vec1.push_back( -20 );
vec1.push_back( -20 );
vec1.push_back( -20 );

for (int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
{
    if(vec[i] ==  vec1[i])
    {
      std::cout<<vec[i]<<"\t"<<vec1[i]<<": Match: \n";
    }
    else {
      std::cout<<vec[i]<<"\t"<<vec1[i]<<":Doesnt Match: \n";
    }

}
```

Output

```
-10 -20:Doesnt Match: 
-20 -20: Match: 
-20 -20: Match: 
-20 -20: Match: 
-20 -20: Match:
```

The output printed here is actually wrong as we just have 4 elements in the second vector , but output shows it has 5 elements .
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Read the docs. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: `if (v1 == v2)` should work.

Comment: Use `vec.size()` instead of `sizeof(vec)`

Comment: "while i am trying to use vectors, it isn't as simple" - actually if you're doing a  slot-for-slot comparison, it's actually *simpler*. And that isn't how `sizeof()` works (as you just found out).

Comment: Dont understand the negative votes, if someone doesn't tell me whats wrong how can i learn.

Comment: Also the output in the for loop is wrong, there are just 4 values i the array and it has cerated a fifth number -20 in vec1.

Comment: @LearningCpp So why not change your `for` loop condition?  `size_t compareSize = std::min(vec.size(), vec2.size()); for (size_t i = 0; i < compareSize; ++i)`.  In other words, change your loop to loop over the smaller of the two vector's sizes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : Thanks, will do that,
But any reason why it is assigning a new value(-20), the actual vec1 doesn't have 5 th element , but the output shows and also matches

Comment: @LearningCpp -- You are accessing an element that's out of bounds using `operator[]`, which is undefined behavior. Change that line to `if(vec.at(i) ==  vec1.at(i))` using your same loop (not the one I suggested) and you will see an exception thrown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : Thank You, Thats perfect

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` defines the `operator ==`, so you can just compare them:

```
  if (a == b)
  {
    std::cout <<": Match ";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout <<":Doesnt Match" ;
  }
```

If you still want to compare each element -

- To get the size of a `vector`, you do `vec.size()`, not `sizeof`.
- But first compare the size of both vectors. If it's not the same then the vectors are obviously not the same.

Comment: How would i get the size of these vectors to compare each index . The for loop to iterate both the vectors

Comment: for (int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) is not as helpful,it actually is creating a new value itself i assume , please check the latest output.
Also, when i change it to for (unsigned int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) , it is probably comparing the first vector's value with  the second vectors junk value which is correct

Comment: It's up to you,  you need to decide what you want to do when the two vectors have a different size, and code it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will update the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `vec.at(i)` instead of `vec[i]`. Because in the second case when index `i=4`, you will call the non-existing element of the vector `vec1`, having only 4 elements [0,1,2,3]. The result of such operation is undefined!
If you will use `vec.at(i)` fucntion, it will not allow to go besides the vector array bounds.

Also the for loop is wrong, you will have to get a warning from compiler about it.
For vectors, it should be something like this:

`for(vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) { .... }`